# Background Activity's local objects being garbage collected by Xamarin Android

Tags: android, android-activity, garbage-collection, xamarin

My app navigates through a stack of Activities (within the same Task)

A -> B -> C

Going foward is okay, but I've noticed after I pop back to B (from C) or to A (from B) that all the CLR objects in that Activity are null. This includes local fields and event handlers.

My guess is that Android internally serializes the Activity stack (ignoring CLR fields) thus leading the CLR GC to collect those Activity's objects. This is obviously not desired and there must surely be a way to prevent this from happening.

Has anyone ever managed to preserve CLR objects of an Activity after it going into the background then being resumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  When you are on activity C, A and B are both in the "Stopped" state, and therefore eligible to be cleaned up (moved to the "Destroyed" state, then garbage collected).  It looks like the relevant article in the documentation is here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

The very basic idea: you override `onSaveInstanceState` and Android will call it when appropriate.  It will then be passed to your `onCreate()` method so you can restore it when the activity is re-created.

**Edit:** There are, of course, alternatives.  You should especially look into alternatives when your state information is bulky, because the method above (de)serializes your state, which can get expensive.

Personally, I tend to save the information I need in a database, and check for it in `onCreate()`, or even `onStart()` (when I need to react to changes effected in other activities, that could happen while this activity is still in memory).  You could also save the information you need to a file, or any other persistent storage.  The difference is that you become responsible for knowing when state should be restored, and when you should start fresh.

Beware that saving state in static variables does not work as well.  Static variables tend to be *more* persistent than the instance variables of an activity, but they can be wiped without notice, e.g. when you get a phone call.

Comment: It's not possible to serialize transient UI objects. Android has a very poor design in comparison to iOS.

Comment: Correct, you should not be trying to save your actual UI objects.  Instead, save the values they represent.  I don't know iOS programming, but I do know it has taken a long time to get used to all the caveats in Android, so I would not be surprised if iOS is easier.